# Can I use std::copy to copy bit pattern of data from vector of integers to an array of unsigned char

Tags: c++, vector, copy, std, memcpy

Recently I have been trying to update some code to utilise the standard C++ library functions rather than old C style functions. In particular, I tried to do the following (artificial working example for simplicity - i know the code is ugly but it illustrates the problem concisely) :

```
std::vector<int> vData;
vData.push_back(10990);
vData.push_back(11990);
vData.push_back(12990);
vData.push_back(13990);

unsigned char szBuffer[100];
memset(szBuffer,0,sizeof(szBuffer));

std::copy(vData.begin(),vData.end(),szBuffer);
```

I was expecting that this would behave in a similar way to the code that I am trying to replace :

```
memcpy(szBuffer,&vData[0],sizeof(int)*vData.size());
```

but debugging the code, it is clear that the `std::copy` code I have written is only writing to the first 4 bytes of the `unsigned char` buffer instead of the full bit pattern of the 4 integers in the vector. Can someone tell me what I have done wrong, or is it simply that I cannot use `std::copy` in this way and should stick with `memcpy` ?

Comment: Well, an alterative to both would be `std::memcpy` from `<cstring>`.

Comment: @ChristianRau: you reckon that would outwit "C++ minus C" programmers, by making them think it's not the same function as `::memcpy`?

Comment: @SteveJessop Hah, nice side effect. No, I just don't like to pollute the global namespace with random rubbish functions (yes I know, the standard allows it to be still polluted) and want to be explicit about using any standard functions vs my own functions. Any library should be in a reasonable namespace and the standard library isn't any different. Well Ok, `memcpy` is pretty unlikely to come from any other third or first party component, but well. In the end you could also say I'm just fond of `std::`s all over the place ;)

Comment: @SteveJessop In the end it is a different function. One is from the C++ standard library and the other from the C standard library, no matter if you're guaranteed to have access to both and that both always result in the exact same function. But then again I'm just one of those *"anti-C bigots"*.

Comment: @SteveJessop *"I think it's guaranteed that they're different names for the same function"* - Yes, this is indeed guaranteed, but I didn't say anything contrary, anyway. You might have interpreted the first sentence of my last comment in that way, but the following sentence should have made clear that I am aware of this fact and talking about conceptual difference. I'm sorry if it didn't.

Comment: Ah, yes, misunderstanding on my part. When you said "both always result in the exact same function" I thought you were saying that's merely the way they're implemented. If I ever think of a situation where it matters whether they're "conceptually different functions" guaranteed to be the same, vs "different names" guaranteed to be aliases, then the minuscule difference between what each of us is emphasizing will become important to me ;-) Until then it's two ways of saying the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stick to `memcpy`, `std::copy` is being intelligent, it understands the types involved and is correctly converting `int` to `unsigned char` using standard conversions. `memcpy` is ignorant, that's what you want.

Answer (score 2):

> I was expecting that this would behave in a similar way to the code that I am trying to replace ...

That `std::copy` as written cannot behave in a similar way to a `std::memcpy` or `std::memmove` because the type mismatch between the elements of `std::vector<int>` versus elements of `unsigned char szBuffer[100]`. One way to overcome this type mismatch is to cast that `szBuffer` to an `int*`:

```
std::copy(vData.begin(),vData.end(),reinterpret_cast<int*>(szBuffer));
```

That `reinterpret_cast` is a personal preference issue. I'd much rather see something that screams "Danger, danger, Will Robinson!" for something that can invoke undefined behavior over a C-style cast that hides but does not remove the potential for UB. I (and my project manager overlords) can grep for `reinterpret_cast`.

The potential for UB here is real as there is no guarantee that this cast is valid due to alignment issues.

Note also that there is no guarantee that `std::copy` will ever be implemented via `memcpy` or `memmove`. There is not one word in the standard (either 2003 or 2011) that says that `std::copy` needs to be implemented via `memcpy` or `memmove` if possible. (Aside: In every implementation I've seen, `std::copy` will be implemented via `std::memmove` if doing so would work "as if" the naive implementation had been employed.)

The only reason to switch from `std::memcpy` to `std::copy` here is aesthetics. Sometimes aesthetics get in the way. "Foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of small minds." I recommend sticking with `std::memcpy`. It does exactly what you want, and this usage is safe because there's no overlap and because the buffer is properly sized.

Comment: Though casting the the source to `unsigned char*` wouldn't be UB in turn, but of course you're totally correct.

Comment: @ChristianRau - Yes, but even this is tricky. Casting the end pointer is UB. Add to this that casting the source involves two reinterpret casts: Double code smell. Why? Just to avoid `memcpy`? That's a "Foolish consistency ..." behavior.

Comment: Indeed, agree with you. I would question the use of an `unsigned char` buffer in the first place. But when needed, `std::memcpy` is there for exactly such things.

Comment: Regarding implementing `copy` using `memcpy` -- `copy` is defined to copy forwards, and the targets can overlap in the direction for which that's OK (source is in the destination range). `memcpy` is less tightly specified, and the targets must not overlap in either direction. `memmove` copies as necessary to deal with overlapping targets. So `copy` actually lies *between* `memmove` and `memcpy`. IIRC glibc guarantees that `memcpy` copies forwards (albeit not one byte at a time), in order that `memmove` can use it in the relevant case, and so can `copy`.

Comment: @SteveJessop - I agree. `std::memmove` has to accommodate any kind of overlap. The standard requires that for `std::copy`, the output iterator/pointer itself must not lie between `[begin,end)`. That eliminates a large class of overlaps.

Comment: @SteveJessop - glibc guarantees nothing about how `memcpy` is implemented. All that the standard says is that *The `memcpy` function copies `n` characters from the object pointed to by `s2` into the object pointed to by `s1`. If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.* The implementation can implement `memcpy` any way it wants so long as the end result for non-overlapping memory is indeed a true copy.

Comment: @ChristianRau Why would you question the unsigned char array?? I have to write raw bytes to a serial port - I would welcome any alternative suggestion you may have?

Comment: @mathematician1975 Well, that might be exactly one of the cases (addressed in my comment by the *"but when needed"*-part) where an `unsigned char` array might make sense, and where `std::memcpy` is your friend.

Comment: @DavidHammen: hmm, OK I don't remember correctly then. If not glibc then there was some other standard library implementation I saw, in which memmove called memcpy in the case where a copy-forwards would work (destination not in the source range rounded out to the size of chunk that `memcpy` actually copied), because that was guaranteed to be the implementation. I know what the standard says, but just because the standard doesn't guarantee something does not mean that a particular implementation doesn't.

Comment: And my main point in my original comment was just that `memcpy` *would* have to guarantee something extra in order for it to be useful to implement `std::copy`.

Answer (score 1):

because the standard of is that the behaviour (if not the exact implementation) of 
`std::copy`  is equivalent to:

```
namespace std { 
  template< typename InIter, typename OutIter >
  OutIter std::copy( InIter begin, InIter end, OutIter outp )
  {
     for( ; begin != end; ++begin, ++outp )
     {
         *outp = *begin;
     }
     return outp;
  }
}
```

which means it copies member-by-member, incrementing each iterator and returns the next write position in the output.

This is not the same behaviour as memcpy which is what you actually want here. There is nothing wrong with using memcpy (even if a certain Microsoft compiler tells you it is unsafe, which it can be but so is driving a truck if you don't drive it properly, that doesn't mean nobody can ever drive one).

Answer (score 1):

To interpret the vector's contents as raw memory, use `reinterpret_cast` to `unsigned char *`:

```
std::copy(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&*vData.begin()),
          reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&*vData.end()), szBuffer);
```

You need to indirect and take the address of the begin and end elements because it is not guaranteed that `vector::iterator` is a pointer type.

This is one of the few guaranteed safe uses of `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: That's techinically UB, as you're dereferencing the end iterator.  I would recommend using `&vData.front()` and `&vData.back() + 1`, which is both easier to read and avoids the problem.  Or, use `&vData.front() + vData.size()`, if you don't like the  + 1 in the first statement.

Comment: This is arguably uglier than just using `memcpy`. At some point, it's important to ask which is a bigger code smell: Using standard C library functions (which is perfectly valid), or uglifying the code just to avoid all things C.